# Concatenate rows with not really following number

Tags: sql, db2

I have a table which contains rows i would like to concat.
I need to group by ID1, ID2 and concate each T type with parent A type based on line number.

This is what i have :

```
with t as (
    select '123' as ID1, '0' as ID2, 1500 as LINE, 'A' as type, 'First line ' as txt from sysibm.sysdummy1
    union all
    select '123' as ID1, '0' as ID2, 1510 as LINE, 'T' as type, 'It' as txt from sysibm.sysdummy1
    union all
    select '123' as ID1, '0' as ID2, 1520 as LINE, 'T' as type, 'works' as txt from sysibm.sysdummy1
    union all
    select '123' as ID1, '0' as ID2, 1530 as LINE, 'T' as type, 'very' as txt from sysibm.sysdummy1
    union all
    select '123' as ID1, '0' as ID2, 1540 as LINE, 'T' as type, 'well !' as txt from sysibm.sysdummy1
    union all
    select '123' as ID1, '0' as ID2, 2000 as LINE, 'A' as type, 'Second line' as txt from sysibm.sysdummy1
    union all
    select '123' as ID1, '0' as ID2, 2010 as LINE, 'T' as type, 'i am' as txt from sysibm.sysdummy1
    union all
    select '123' as ID1, '0' as ID2, 2020 as LINE, 'T' as type, 'happy.' as txt from sysibm.sysdummy1
    union all
    select '123' as ID1, '1' as ID2, 1500 as LINE, 'A' as type, 'Another line' as txt from sysibm.sysdummy1
    union all
    select '123' as ID1, '1' as ID2, 1510 as LINE, 'T' as type, 'It''s' as txt from sysibm.sysdummy1
    union all
    select '123' as ID1, '1' as ID2, 1520 as LINE, 'T' as type, 'a' as txt from sysibm.sysdummy1
    union all
    select '123' as ID1, '1' as ID2, 1530 as LINE, 'T' as type, 'pleasure' as txt from sysibm.sysdummy1
    union all
    select '123' as ID1, '1' as ID2, 1540 as LINE, 'T' as type, 'to' as txt from sysibm.sysdummy1
    union all
    select '123' as ID1, '1' as ID2, 1550 as LINE, 'T' as type, 'read' as txt from sysibm.sysdummy1
    union all
    select '123' as ID1, '1' as ID2, 1560 as LINE, 'T' as type, '!' as txt from sysibm.sysdummy1
    union all
    select '123' as ID1, '1' as ID2, 2100 as LINE, 'A' as type, 'Line without details' as txt from sysibm.sysdummy1
    union all
    select '456' as ID1, '0' as ID2, 1500 as LINE, 'A' as type, 'This is not the same id' as txt from sysibm.sysdummy1
)
select *
from t
```

This is what i want :

```
with t as (
select '123' as ID1, '0' as ID2, 1500 as LINE, 'First line It works very well !' as txt from sysibm.sysdummy1
union all
select '123' as ID1, '0' as ID2, 2000 as LINE, 'Second line i am happy.' as txt from sysibm.sysdummy1
union all
select '123' as ID1, '1' as ID2, 1500 as LINE, 'Another line It''s a pleasure to read !' as txt from sysibm.sysdummy1
union all
select '123' as ID1, '1' as ID2, 2100 as LINE, 'Line without details' as txt from sysibm.sysdummy1
union all
select '456' as ID1, '0' as ID2, 1500 as LINE, 'This is not the same id' as txt from sysibm.sysdummy1
)
select *
from t
```

Do you have an idea ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Assumed you want a table, not a SQL statement, try this:

```
select id1,id2,line / 100 * 100, listagg(txt,' ') within group (order by type,line)
from   t
group  by id1,id2,line / 100
```

Comment: Hello, thank you. But i have this : SQL0122 - Column LINE or expression in SELECT list not valid.
I tried to remove the last / 100. I don't have error anymore but the result is not what i want...
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
/*
with t as (
...
)
*/
select 
  id1, id2
, min (case type when 'A' then line end) line
, listagg (txt, ' ') within group (order by type, line) txt
from
(
select 
  t.*
, sum (case type when 'A' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by id1, id2 order by line) grp
from t
)
group by id1, id2, grp
```

We construct an artificial group `grp` inside `id1, id2`. Every time we face type = 'A' within `id1, id2`, this group number increments by 1.

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=803f70b12f638c1543511c3180ac695c) link.